# Maya - Black triangles when viewing model from a distance

Tags: maya

Everything was fine while working on a model in Maya, until randomly, numerous black triangles started appearing all over my model. They seem to go away when I zoom in closely with the camera:

[image: MayaProblems]

This issue seems to be associated with my particular project, I am able to open and view my other models without any problems. Opening this file on another machine has an error message in the Output Window:
"Maya binary file parse error:  : (6) corrupted file structure"

I've tried Googling around and tried (without success):

- Normals -> Set To Face
- Normals -> Unlock
- Normals -> Reverse
- Changing various renderer settings

Here's a download link to my .mb:
http://www.filedropper.com/herocharacter

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Found a fix by exporting my whole mesh as a .OBJ and reimporting into a new scene.

Not sure if this fix would have worked if I had rigging/animation data present.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/pArJG.png

Comment: I'd guess either normals reversed, or you've got duplicate polygons that are very close if not exactly the same.  From close up, the math precision is enough to keep them separate, but when you pull back the math errors begin to kick in and create some Z fighting.